# Left join when there are lots of matched rows from right table

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have two tables.

```
Product(id, name)
LineItem(id, product_id, order_id)
Order(id, state)
```

Order can have many products. One product can belong to many orders at the same time.

I would like to select Products, which don't have orders with specific statuses(i.e. 1, 2).

**My query is**

```
SELECT products.id, products.price
  FROM "products"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN line_items ON line_items.product_id = products.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON orders.id = line_items.order_id AND orders.status IN (1, 2)
    WHERE (products.price > 0) AND (orders.id IS NULL) AND "products"."id" = $1
    GROUP BY products.id, products.price  [["id", 11]]
```

11 is an id of a product, that should not appear to the result, but it does.

Comment: Post your query. Will be helpful to guide you

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are really using.

Comment: Jim I have posted it. Please review

Comment: s/I have two tables/I have three tables/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I would like to select Products, which don't have orders with specific statuses(i.e. 1, 2).`

```
SELECT * FROM products p    -- I would like to select Products
WHERE NOT EXISTS(           --  , which don't have
    SELECT *
    FROM orders o           -- orders 
    JOIN line_items li ON li.order_id = o.id
    WHERE li.product_id = p.id
    AND o.status IN (1,2) -- with specific statuses(i.e. 1, 2).
    );
```

Comment: Best answer in my opinion. And a great explanation on how the English phrase translates into code. I like that. When looking for non-existence one should use `NOT EXISTS`. (Or `NOT IN` for that matter: select all products that are not in the set of orders with the specific statuses.)

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.id, p.name
from products p
join lineitem l on l.product_id = p.id
join `order` o on l.order_id = o.id
group by p.id, p.name
having sum(case when o.state in (1,2) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to start with the products table and use `left join` to find orders with 1 or 2.  If they don't exist, then you want the product:

```
select p.id, p.name
from product p left join
     lineitem li
     on li.product_id = p.id left join
     orders o  -- a better name for the table
     on li.order_id = o.id and
        o.state in (1, 2)
where o.id is null
group by p.id, p.name;
```

Comment: Your idea is perfect. But I can't understand why this does not work. I still have all records without filtering. Please could you review your sql query? BTW: I voted your answer.

Comment: even better could you review my query I wrote on the description of the topic.

Comment: Hmmm, this should choose products that have no orders with a state of either 1 or 2.  As for your query, you have `left join`s but they are converted to inner joins by the `where` clause.

Comment: Please write the answer. I spent all day to solve it. No result :(. Please help.